# Show total amount of unique records in mySQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to complete an assignment where I have 1 million records in a mySQL database, each record has a URL and a referring URL (as well as an ID of course). Part of the objective of the assignment is to show the top 5 occurring URL's by "view" (AKA: how often each URL is a record in the db)

I believe I'm very close, as at the moment I have the top 5 URL's showing, but my issue is that I can only get the total number of records to show (either 1000000 or each consecutive URL's views following each other in the same line)

My Controller code looks like this:
(The URL's being the only ones occurring in the database)

```
@url = Url.where({ url: ["http://apple.com", "https://apple.com", "https://www.apple.com", "http://developer.apple.com", "http://en.wikipedia.org", "http://opensource.org"]}).group("url").limit(5).order(:created_at)
@viewcount = @url.count
```

My view code looks like this:

```
<% @url.each do |url| %>
<%= url.url %> Views: <%= @viewcount %>
<% end %>
```

This is how it's being displayed currently:

```
1st URL Views: {"1st URL"=>166420, "2nd URL"=>166182, "3rd URL"=>166804, "4th URL"=>167351, "5th URL"=>165933}

2nd URL Views: {"1st URL"=>166420, "2nd URL"=>166182, "3rd URL"=>166804, "4th URL"=>167351, "5th URL"=>165933}

3rd URL Views: {"1st URL"=>166420, "2nd URL"=>166182, "3rd URL"=>166804, "4th URL"=>167351, "5th URL"=>165933}

4th URL Views: {"1st URL"=>166420, "2nd URL"=>166182, "3rd URL"=>166804, "4th URL"=>167351, "5th URL"=>165933}

5th URL Views: {"1st URL"=>166420, "2nd URL"=>166182, "3rd URL"=>166804, "4th URL"=>167351, "5th URL"=>165933}
```

I'm assuming the issue is with my "where" statement in the controller, and I may even be getting redundant with that second line unnecessarily.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

This is the code generated by the log:

```
Started GET "/top_urls" for ::1 at 2015-02-16 11:46:06 -0700
Processing by PagestatsController#top_urls as HTML
[1m[35m (4077.3ms)[0m  SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count_all, url AS url FROM `urls` WHERE `urls`.`url` IN ('http://apple.com', 'https://apple.com', 'https://www.apple.com', 'http://developer.apple.com', 'http://en.wikipedia.org', 'http://opensource.org') GROUP BY url  ORDER BY `urls`.`created_at` ASC LIMIT 5
[1m[36mUrl Load (4600.9ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `urls`.* FROM `urls` WHERE `urls`.`url` IN ('http://apple.com', 'https://apple.com', 'https://www.apple.com', 'http://developer.apple.com', 'http://en.wikipedia.org', 'http://opensource.org') GROUP BY url  ORDER BY `urls`.`created_at` ASC LIMIT 5[0m
Rendered pagestats/top_urls.html.erb within layouts/application (4608.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8735ms (Views: 42.0ms | ActiveRecord: 8687.0ms)
```

Comment: What query is being generated? Have a look in `log/development.log` to see if it's what you want.

Comment: I get: SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count_all, url AS url FROM `urls` WHERE `urls`.`url` IN ('http://apple.com', 'https://apple.com', 'https://www.apple.com', 'http://developer.apple.com', 'http://en.wikipedia.org', 'http://opensource.org') GROUP BY url  ORDER BY `urls`.`created_at` ASC LIMIT 5
  [1m[36mUrl Load (4600.9ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `urls`.* FROM `urls` WHERE `urls`.`url` IN ('http://apple.com', 'https://apple.com', 'https://www.apple.com', 'http://developer.apple.com', 'http://en.wikipedia.org', 'http://opensource.org') GROUP BY url  ORDER BY `urls`.`created_at` ASC LIMIT 5

Comment: As a note, that would look a lot less mangled if you just appended it to your question. Strangely that should return a singular count, not a count per item.

Comment: Right?! And sorry, I'm a n00b here..

Comment: I received a "Statement Invalid" error:

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'count_all' in 'order clause': SELECT  `urls`.* FROM `urls` GROUP BY url  ORDER BY count_all LIMIT 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :
`@urls = Url.group('url').order('count(*) desc').limit(5).count`

It will return a hash with url as key and view as value.

Update your view code :

```
<% @urls.each do |url, view_count| %>
<%= url %> Views: <%= view_count %>
<% end %>
```